# My javascript code won't execute, even tough my console doesn't give any errors

Tags: javascript, onclick, onhover

I'm trying to show a map when I click on an h1 element. So I wrote my code which should do the trick but nothing happens. So I went looking for my JS console in my browser and there weren't any errors so I'm kinda stuck right now. Anyone that can help me out?

```
my HTML:
<section class="WT1">
<h1>Wetenschap & Techniek - Ellermanstraat &#8595</h1>
<div id="mapid"></div>
</section>


my JS
var touchMe = document.getElementsByTagName('h1');

touchMe.onhover = function() {
touchMe.style.cursor = 'pointer';
}

touchMe.onclick = function() {
document.getElementById('mapid').style.display = "block";
};
```

Comment: first confirm, you are running code after getting DOM ready

Answer (score 3):

`getElementsByTagName` returns an array of elements, select one item from it

```
var touchMe = document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0]
```

Comment: @brk, yeah, I know that it's NodeList, but it can be used like array

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_nodelist.asp

Comment: `Changed the return value from NodeList to HTMLCollection`, looks like they changed it